# UIScrollView resizing according to content

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, size, uilabel

guys! So, i have UIScrollView and several UILabels on it, and i want to resize UIScrollView so its height will fit to sum of all labels height. can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum the heights of the labels, add some padding and set it as the height of the scroll view's frame (or contentView, if larger than the screen).

Comment: i know this way, but is there any other more simply way to do this?